# Autogenerated Date Time Log

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

How can I generate other log file which will not overwrite the first result's output.

Here is my `.bat` file code:

```
sqlcmd -S BernsDBServer -d BernsTable -i "\\BernsRemoteServer\d$\Tools\DeleteNullValues.sql" -s " | " -o "\\BernsRemoteServer\d$\Tools\log.txt"
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! What do you mean by "will not overwrite the first output"?

Comment: To append as opposed to overwrite, you can drop the `-o` option and use cmd.exe redirection instead. e.g. `SQLCmd -S BernsDBServer -d BernsTable -i "\\BernsRemoteServer\d$\Tools\DeleteNullValues.sql" -s " | " >> "\\BernsRemoteServer\d$\Tools\log.txt"`. I would advise that you change directory first, and shorten those lines too. `PushD "\\BernsRemoteServer\d$\Tools"` then you can use, `SQLCmd -S BernsDBServer -d BernsTable -i "DeleteNullValues.sql" -s " | " >> "log.txt"`. `PopD` would then return the current directory to what it was before the `PushD` command line.

Comment: Hi Hongsy.. What I mean is if the bat. file has executed a log.txt file will be generated and if they executed again they will not overwrite the first result.